# SQL connection string on domain C#

Tags: c#, sql

I moved a webapp from my personal machine to my work machine, along with the database I've been using to test. When clicking the submit button that inserts the data, I get the error, can't find server/instance. I'm thinking that being on a domain here is part of the problem. Here is my connection string, and I've tried several forms of it already.

```
Data Source=\\bkirkland_lpt.domain.com\brandon;Initial Catalog=STATUS;integrated security=SSPI;persist security info=False;Trusted_Connection=Yes;");
```

Comment: That's not a valid `Data Source`.  SQL Server isn't UNC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple problems here.

First, it looks like you are using the wrong data source.  The data source should be in the format [ServerName]\[InstanceName].  Based on your code, I would suggest

```
Data Source=bkirkland_lpt.domain.com\brandon;Initial Catalog=STATUS;integrated security=SSPI;persist security info=False;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
```

Additionally, I notice you are using Integrated Security.  This means that the user you are running under must be granted permissions on the database.  My guess is that your domain user does not have access to the database that you moved.

Comment: I created the db and the instance. This is all on my local machine. My machine is bkirkland_lpt.

Comment: Removed slashes and it still doesn't work. I was able to add the db as a data connection with no problem. It shows up as, bkirkland_lpt\brandon

Answer (score 0):

\bkirkland_lpt.servicesource.com\brandon is a shared folder path, not a host name. Try bkirkland_lpt.servicesource.com

Comment: The instance name is BRANDON.

Comment: anyway you should remove leading slashes

Answer (score 0):

Try to enclose the server name in `[]`. Try to replace the servername with localhost and see if it makes any difference (if it is all on your local machine). I also would use proper casing and True vs Yes as parameter value.

```
Data Source=[bkirkland_lpt.domain.com]\brandon;Initial Catalog=STATUS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Trusted_Connection=True;

Data Source=localhost\brandon;Initial Catalog=STATUS;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Trusted_Connection=True;
```